# Reload bxSlider in callback

Tags: bxslider

Hi I have a problem with bxSlider. I display 6 images in slider, and after the last one I want to dynamically add new content. Everything works fine to this moment, but now I can't reload the slider. This is my coffescript:

```
slider = $('#my_slider').bxSlider
      pager: false,
      controls: false,
      mode: 'fade',
      auto: true,
      pause: 6000,
      preloadImages: 'all',
      onSlideNext: ($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) ->
        if oldIndex == $('.feed-gallery-list li').length - 1
          $.get('/inside/board/top_feeds').done (data) ->
            if data.html.length > 0
              $('#top_feed').html(data.html)
              slider.reloadSlider()
```

It just looks like the last line of code (reloadSlider() ) doesn't work, but I don't see any errors in a chrome console. What can be a problem here?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: OK I got it... It turned out that you can't reload all div with slider, just only insert new content inside it. Now it works perfectly.